# TCL in Python: can't find package

Tags: python, tcl

I am trying to run a TCL script from python.  There is a very specific TCL package embedded in some software I am using and I need to tell the python interpreter (or TKinter ?) where this package is.  Here is what I have tried so far.

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> r = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> r.tk.eval('lappend auto_path C:/Program Files (x86)/Ixia/IxNetwork/7.0-EA/tcl8.4/bin')
>>> r.tk.eval('lappend auto_path C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ixia\\IxNetwork\7.0-EA\\tcl8.4\\bin\\')
'{C:\\Python26\\tcl\\tcl8.5} C:/Python26/tcl C:/lib {C:\\Python26\\tcl\\tk8.5} {C:\\Python26\\tcl\\tk8.5/ttk} C:/Program Files (x86)/Ixia/IxNetwork/7.0-EA/tcl8.4/bin C:Program Files (x86)IxiaIxNetwork\x07.0-EA\\tcl8.4\x08in\\\\'
```

I want to use the following TCL shell which I copied from the windows start menu:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxOS\6.40-EA\TclScripts\bin\wish84.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxOS\6.40-EA\TclScripts\bin\IxiaWish.tcl"
```

Firstly, can someone tell me why there are two items being referred to in the start menu shortcut target?  Will I be able to access this for my TCL in python?

As you can see from above, I have tried appending this package to the auto_path, but there are problems with characters.  Does anyone know why the characters are mixed up?

Comment: just [`source`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/source.htm) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. If all you want to do is to execute the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxOS\6.40-EA\TclScripts\bin\wish84.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxOS\6.40-EA\TclScripts\bin\IxiaWish.tcl"
```

Then why not use `subprocess`? Something along this line:

```
import subprocess
command = [
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxOS\6.40-EA\TclScripts\bin\wish84.exe',
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxOS\6.40-EA\TclScripts\bin\IxiaWish.tcl'
]
p = subprocess.Popen(commands, 
        shell=True, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```